# have so much the start of/on/over us

Tags: prepositions

This is from The Golden Spruce by John Vaillant

> Although we have harbours and pineries not one whit inferior to
>   theirs... they, *having so much the start **of** us*, have thoroughly
>   established trade, whereas we have to a great extent yet to make
>   ourselves known abroad.

I have seen the idiom 'have a head start on/over someone'  So my logic goes that the '**of**' in the *italic part* above can be replaced with **on/over**. Would it be natural to your ears?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have "a head start" on us.  They were doing this before we were.  This **the start of** is just an older collocation. **the start of us** hasn't really been in use for the last two hundred years.

**The start on** is a century or so more modern than **the start of** but it too has largely fallen by the wayside except in regional dialects.